# MySQL : ERROR 1064 (42000) SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a database named "crea" with a table named "assets" and in this table i have 11 column named  (name,description,assetType,local,temporary,data,id,create_time,access_time,asset_flags,CreatorID)

I also have a directory folder with many picture in .jp2 format (xxxx.jp2)

What im trying to do is to bulk insert these picture in the table "assets" of my database, so i decided to do it with 2 shell scripts, the both are in the directory with the pictures.

When i launch ./assetadd.sh from the terminal, i get this error from MySQL :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '??,asset_flags,CreatorID) VALUES at line 1

I dont understan what is wrong with these scripts and where the syntax error is … i checked many time the name of the table/column to see if i have made an error but all look good.

If someone have a little time to take a look a these scripts and tell me what is wrong this will be really apreciated.

Thank you

PS: My OS is Ubuntu 11.10

***- Script 1 : assetsadd.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$(pwd)
find $path/ -type f \( -iname *.jp2 \) -exec ./insertjp2.sh {} \;

echo "finished!!"
```

***- Script 2 : insertjp2.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

user="crea"
password="crea"
database="crea"
dbhost="localhost"
creator="crea"

param=$@
basenam=${param##*/}
filenam=${basenam%.*}

MYSQL=`/usr/bin/mysql -u$user -p$password -D$database -e"INSERT INTO assets (name,description,assetType,local,temporary,data,id,create_time,access_time​,asset_flags,CreatorID) VALUES ('$filenam','$filenam',0,0,0,LOAD_FILE('$param'),'$filenam',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),1325304546,0,'$creator' );"`

echo $param >> assetadd.log
echo $MYSQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a weird or non-printable character right at the point of the error message:

```
access_time​,asset_flags
           ^
```

Comment: whats does that mean ? I cant delete the coma.

Comment: I know MySQL reported the error there but in the script i cant see it. Is the coma the error ? how can i correct it ?

Comment: Ok i just figured out that was a space. Thank you :)